# Convert in react 18.2.0, router-dom v6 and mui 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

How to convert the below file or code into react latest version and react-router-dom v6 I have tried by myself but unable to do that because I got error and unable to understand createBrowserHistory. and my routes in json file and also need auth guard.

```
import React, { Suspense, Fragment } from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import { routes } from "src/routes";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import AuthGuard from "src/component/AuthGuard";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { createTheme } from "src/theme";
import { UserContext } from "./context/User";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
function App() {
  const theme = createTheme();
  console.log(theme);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
          <AuthContext>
            <Router history={history}>
              <RenderRoutes data={routes} />
            </Router>
          </AuthContext>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
function RenderRoutes(props) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
      <Switch>
        {props.data.map((route, i) => {
          const Component = route.component;
          const Guard = route.guard ? AuthGuard : Fragment;
          const Layout = route.layout || Fragment;
          return (
            <Route
              exact={route.exact}
              key={i}
              path={route.path}
              render={(props) => (
                <Guard>
                  <Layout>
                    {route.routes ? (
                      <RenderRoutes data={route.routes} />
                    ) : (
                      <Component {...props} />
                    )}
                  </Layout>
                </Guard>
              )}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

`react-router-dom@6` introduced ***many*** breaking changes from RRDv5.

- The code is importing low-level [`Router`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router) component but fails to pass required props. `history` isn't an accepted prop at all.

  ```
  declare function Router(
    props: RouterProps
  ): React.ReactElement | null;

  interface RouterProps {
    basename?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- required!
    navigationType?: NavigationType;
    navigator: Navigator; // <-- required!
    static?: boolean;
  }
  ```
- RRDv6 doesn't export a `Switch` component, it was replaced by the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) component.
- The `Route` component no longer uses any `component`, or `render` or `children` function props, all were replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, prop value.

## Solution

- Import and use the high-level `BrowserRouter` component.
- Import `Routes` and replace the `Switch` usage.
- Refactor the route mapping to use the correct props/JSX.
- Route props were also removed, if the mapped-to `Component` needs to access the old "route props" (*i.e. `history`, `location`, `match`*) then it should use the RRDv6 React hooks: [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate), [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location), and [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params).

Code:

```
import React, { Suspense, Fragment } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, // <-- import BrowserRouter
  Routes, // <-- import Routes
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
...

const theme = createTheme();

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
          <AuthContext>
            <Router>
              <RenderRoutes data={routes} />
            </Router>
          </AuthContext>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
function RenderRoutes(props) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
      <Routes>
        {props.data.map((route) => {
          const Component = route.component;
          const Guard = route.guard ? AuthGuard : Fragment;
          const Layout = route.layout || Fragment;
          return (
            <Route
              key={route.path}
              path={route.path}
              element={( // <-- render on element prop
                <Guard>
                  <Layout>
                    {route.routes ? (
                      <RenderRoutes data={route.routes} />
                    ) : (
                      <Component />
                    )}
                  </Layout>
                </Guard>
              )}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much I have done this before but I have forget to replace render to element.Now I am using the useRouter hook for routing I just want to ask you which approach should I use for my project using the useRouter or I approached that I have ask in question

Comment: @Bhupender Certainly, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm then use this to update react and react-router-dom
`npm install react@latest react-router-dom@latest` 
and use `npm update @material-ui/core`

Comment: I have tried that but I got error in createBrowserHistory also I want to optimized that code as well.